# Replace variables after retrieving string from sql

Tags: c#, mysql

I would like for C# to detect the variables in my mailbody and replace them with the values each of them already has in my method.
I'm saving my mails in a TEXT datatype in mysql
This is what i save into my Text:

```
<html>
    <h1>
        <span style='text-decoration: underline;'>
            <strong>Solicitud</strong>
        </span>
    </h1>
    <br/>" + "<body>Blabla" + user.Nombre + " " + user.Apellido + " p<br/>La razón a que: <br />"+ razon+ ".</body>
</html>
```

I want it to replace user.Nombre user.Apellido and razon which are variables already available in the method

For example if my method has:

- user.Nombre = "MATT";
- user.Apellido ="CASA";
- razon = "why not?";

Then detecting the variables i would have:

```
    <html>
    <h1>
        <span style='text-decoration: underline;'>
            <strong>Solicitud</strong>
        </span>
    </h1>
    <br/>" + "<body>Blabla" + "MATT"+ " " + "CASA" + " p<br/>La razón a que: <br />"+ "Why not?"+ ".</body>
</html>
```

The problem is making C# detect that the string already has variables inside of it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, which is pretty hard given then English you have used.

You want to replace a parts of a string you retrieved from a database?

You can perform string replacements like the below example.

```
string email = emailAsString.Replace("+ user.Nombre +", variable1);
```

You can read more on this here, if you so wish.

[String Replace - https://www.dotnetperls.com/replace](https://www.dotnetperls.com/replace)

Comment: Sory, now i have edited it, my problem is making C# detect that the string already has code inside of it , not a block of characters

Answer (score 0):

Well searched far and wide in the web, there is a method to compile manually but its highly dangerous so I decided to use String.Format , and the templates of my mails swap the "+ variable +" to {#}
[Interpolating a string stored in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38355578/interpolating-a-string-stored-in-a-database)

After retrieving use:
var formatedString= String.Format(string , variables);